# Is it possible to delete assets I've just created?

Tags: assets

Is it possible to delete an asset from mainnet? I just created a duplicate asset and want to delete the old one.

Answer (score 6):

***Disclaimer: Deleting assets can be dangerous since they may hold real value. Once they are deleted it may be impossible to get them back. Please be careful when deleting assets and only do so at your own risk***.

---

In order to **delete** the asset you will need to *remove the asset from the system altogether*, i.e. you will need to remove all `tokens` and `trustlines`. You will need to control all the account holders to achieve this.

Note: *a `token` is an instance of an `asset`; this is similar to the relationship that an **object** has to a **class** in object-oriented programming*.

---

To remove the **tokens** send them back to the **issuer** account using a [payment operation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#payment). This will remove these **tokens** from the system.

To remove the **trustlines** you need to **set the trust limit for the asset to `0` on all accounts that currently trust this asset**. This can be achieved using the [change trust operation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#change-trust).

Once these two steps are completed your asset will be removed from the system.

Note: *you can only remove a trustline on an account that has a `0` balance for that asset*.

---

**You can view your asset and the total number of account holders using the [All Assets endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/assets-all.html) in Horizon**. The `num_accounts` and `amount` field should be `0` to indicate that no account is holding the asset.

Note: *your asset will always show up in this endpoint and cannot currently be removed*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can
Move all asset to another account, and remove the trust line of old asset from Dist account

> Set Trust Limit to 0 to remove the trust line.